# How to programmatically change seekbar time and enable full screen in youtube iframe api using webView?

Tags: android, webview, kotlin, youtube-iframe-api, autoplay

```
val frameVideo = "<html>
                    <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\n" +
                     "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'>
                      </script>
                      <script type='text/javascript'>\n" +
                        "var player;\n" +
                        "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\n" +
                        "{player=new YT.Player('playerId',{events {onReady:onPlayerReady}})}\n" +
                        "function onPlayerReady(event){player.playVideo();}\n" +
                      "</script>\n" +
                        "<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%' height='100%'\n" +
                         "src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + mVideoId + "?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\n" +
                   "</body>
                 </html>"

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com", frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
```

Replace `$mVideoId` with your video id.

I have tried above code and it's working fine for autoplay but it doesn't show fullscreen button as enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
 val frameVideo = "<html>
                    <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\n" +
                     "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'>
                      </script>
                      <script type='text/javascript'>\n" +
                        "var player;\n" +
                        "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\n" +
                        "{player=new YT.Player('playerId',{events {onReady:onPlayerReady}})}\n" +
                        "function onPlayerReady(event){player.playVideo(); player.seekTo(mNubmer,true);}\n" +
                      "</script>\n" +
                        "<iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%' height='100%'\n" +
                         "src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + mVideoId + "?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>\n"+
                   "</body>
                 </html>"

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com", frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
```

For adding seekbar to youtube-iframe api, add `player.seekTo(mNubmer,true);`.

Replace `$mNumber` with your time in seconds(non-decimal value).

Add `allowfullscreen` to enable full screen in iframe API.